# dict to simulate switch operator

Tags: python, python-3.x

In my textbook I read that a newbie needs some time to recognize this construction:

```
choice = 'ham'
print ({
    'spam': 1.25, 
    'ham': 1.99,
    'eggs': 0.99,
    'bacon': 1.10
}[choice])
```

With the result:

```
The result is 1.99
```

To tell the truth, I can't even grasp a tail of the knot to tell nothing of untying it.  Could you clarify it to me a bit?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: It's perfectly valid to use a dict to cover the same use case many C or Java developers use a switch statement for.

Comment: I know that, but I'm curious which book is teaching it in this _syntax_ especially for beginners.

Comment: Learning python by Mark Lutz. I like it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why doesn't Python have a switch statement?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/374239/why-doesnt-python-have-a-switch-statement)

Answer (score 5):

It's a python dictionary literal, combined with a lookup using `choice` as a key:

```
mapping = {'spam': 1.25, 'ham': 1.99, 'eggs': 0.99, 'bacon': 1.10}
choice = 'ham'
price = mapping[choice]
print(price)
```

Answer (score 3):

You might even stick a .get in there to return a value if the choice isn't in the dictionary.

```
mapping = {'spam': 1.25, 'ham': 1.99, 'eggs': 0.99, 'bacon': 1.10}
choice = 'beans'
price = mapping.get(choice, 'not listed')
print(price)
```

will return

```
not listed
```